# How to find integer solution of this equation?

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

I am trying to find pairs of integers $(x,y)$ $(x >0, y >0)$ satisfying
$$(x + y) (5 x + y)^3 + x y^3 = (5 x + y)^3 + x^2 y^3 + x y^4 $$
I tried

```
SolveValues[(x + y) (5 x + y)^3 + x y^3 == (5 x + y)^3 + x^2 y^3 + 
    x y^4 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}, Integers]
```

I can not get the results $(8,40)$ and $(216, 216)$. How can I get solutions if we do not know $(8,40)$ and $(216, 216)$ are solutions?

Comment: Are you looking for a single solution?  A fixed number of solutions?  All solutions within some bounded domain?  A characterization of the complete solution set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show, this two solutions are all possible solutions with variable transformation.

```
feq = Subtract @@ ((x + y) (5 x + y)^3 + x y^3 == (5 x + y)^3 + 
      x^2 y^3 + x y^4) // Expand

Solve[0 == feq && x > 0 && y > 0, {y}, Integers] // ToRadicals // 
 FullSimplify[#, x > 0] &

(*   {{y -> ConditionalExpression[(
    5 x)/(-1 + x^(1/3)), (x | y) \[Element] Integers && x >= 2]}}   *)

sol = First@Solve[x^(1/3) == xx, x]

y == (5 x)/(-1 + x^(1/3)) /. sol // Simplify[#, xx > 1] &

(*   5 xx^3 + y == xx y   *)

Solve[5 xx^3 + y == xx y && xx > 1 && y > 0, xx, Integers] /. 
 xx -> x^(1/3)

(*   {{x^(1/3) -> ConditionalExpression[2, y == 40]}, 
      {x^(1/3) -> ConditionalExpression[6, y == 216]}}   *)
```

**Edit**

As the fine comment of @DanielLichtblau (thanks a lot !) shows, from `y == (5 x)/(-1 + x^(1/3))` x^(1/3) , which is my xx, has to be an integer. This is used in the last Solve command.

Comment: From the equation `y == (5 x)/(-1 + x^(1/3))` you know `x` is a cube of an integer, call it `x=t^3`. So the numerator is `5*t^3` and the denominator is `t-1`. This that has no factors in common with `t^3` so it must divide 5. This means either `t=2` or `t=6`, thus `x` is 2^3=8 or 6^3=216. Unless I missed something, this exhausts all cases.

Comment: By the way, you don't really need `Solve`, just some algebra on paper (or in a notebook). Rewrite the equation as `(x + y - 1) ((5 x + y)^3 - x y^3)==0`. The constraints mean the first factor cannot vanish, so we have `(5 x + y)^3 = x y^3`. Take cube roots (these are real-valued) to get `5 x + y=x^(1/3)*y`. Rearrange as `y=5x/(x^(1/3)-1)`.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
FindInstance[(x + y) (5 x + y)^3 + x y^3 == (5 x + y)^3 + x^2 y^3 + x y^4, {x, y}, PositiveIntegers] 
(* {{x -> 8, y -> 40}} *)
```

Also `NSolve` (and `Solve` too) in a restricted domain evaluates all solutions:

```
NSolve[{(x + y) (5 x + y)^3 + x y^3 == (5 x + y)^3 + x^2 y^3 +x y^4,Element[{x, y}, PositiveIntegers ], x < 300, y < 300}, {x,y}]
(*{{x -> 8, y -> 40}, {x -> 216, y -> 216}}*)
```

Comment: I think this is not a completed answer. Because, you used x<300 and y<300.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 The answer is quite correct given the way you have posed the question. One can get finitely many solution only if the solution domain is bounded. Otherwise an equation in two variables has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @PlatoManiac:  That last sentence isn't strictly true if we're only looking at integer solutions.  For example, there are only 12 solutions of $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ over all of the integers, and only two if we want $x >0$ and $y > 0$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Correct I should have been more careful framing the comment and should have considered the Integer domain criteria in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can assume y >= x, but that is needed to find your preferred solutions:

```
Solve[(x + y) (5 x + y)^3 + x y^3 == (5 x + y)^3 + x^2 y^3 + x y^4 && 
x > 0 && y > 0 && y >= x, {x, y}, Integers]
```

returns

```
{{x -> 8, y -> 40}, {x -> 216, y -> 216}}
```